# w3wp randomly crashes with AccessViolationException and TargetInvocationException serving WCF call

Tags: wcf, iis, access-violation, targetinvocationexception

We are observing random (like once in 1-5 days) IIS crash exceptions in the EventLog.
 
Server - Windows Server 2012 R2.

- The first one is access violation (more often):

> Application: w3wp.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>  
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>   Stack:

There are no additional details for this one.

- The other one is target invocation (less often):

> Application: w3wp.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Stack:
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
>   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
>   ... (various stack trace further) ...

We have performed some debugging with a few variations of this TargetInvocationException and by forcibly throwing an exception in specific place we could repeat one of the stack traces, but it had an Inner Exception (here it doesn't) + that didn't crash IIS and normally returned error to client wrapped in FaultException.

Do you think it could be related to changes in .NET 4.0 handling of corrupted process state? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you solve this problem?